# When using dynamic import in a function, how can I specify type info in global variable?

Tags: javascript, typescript

My simplified server code looks like below.

server.ts

```js
import google from "googleapis";

const androidPublisher = google.androidpublisher("v3");

app.use('something', function(req, res, n){
   ...
})

...(only one of the dozens of other methods use androidPublisher)
```

I am importing `googleapis` library in order to setup `androidpublisher` variable. However, this `googleapis` library is big and it takes 400ms~700ms to fully import file, when it takes 10ms~30ms to import other library files.

Because my environment is serverless architecture (firebase functions), AND because approximately 1 out of 100 requests actually need `androidPublisher`, I want to take advantage of dynamic import to import `googleapis` when it is necessary. Otherwise, above setup actually adds 400ms/700ms latency to every request that spins up new serverless instance, even when `androidPublisher` is not needed.

So I have made changes like below.

server.ts

```js
let androidPublisherInstance:any;

async function getAndroidPublisher() {
    const googleapis = await import("googleapis");

    if (androidPublisherInstance === undefined) {
        const ap = googleapis.google.androidpublisher("v3");
        androidPublisherInstance = ap;
    }
    return androidPublisherInstance;
}


...(one of methods use getAndroidPublisher() to get androidPublisher instance)
```

with above setup where I am using global variable & helper function to initialize androidPublisher only when needed. This works as intended and 400ms~700ms latency gets added when androidPublisher is needed for the first time. However, I ended up with type of `androidPublisherInstance` to be `any`. I couldn't correctly define the type because type definition is available inside of `googleapis` and that is residing inside of `getAndroidPublisher` function.

Thus, I lose all benefit of using typescript and have to play guess games while using methods/properties when I use `androidPublisherInstance`.

And I think I must use global variable, because I do not want to initialize androidPublisher multiple times (`googleapis.google.androidpublisher("v3")`) whenever a function calls `getAndroidPublisher()`

Am I missing something? Is there a way to use dynamic import & let client to be initialized only once without needing to use global variable?

Comment: What is the type supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just import the type. As long as you use it only in type definitions, not in value expressions, the compiled JavaScript will never load the module:

```
import { androidpublisher_v3 } from "googleapis";
let androidpublisher: androidpublisher_v3 | undefined;
```

Alternatively, to make sure you don't accidentally reference it in the wrong place, use only [import types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#import-types):

```
let androidpublisher: import("googleapis").androidpublisher_v3 | undefined;
```

Comment: If another type that I want to import looks like this... `getClient(): Promise<Compute | JWT | UserRefreshClient>;` does that mean I have to lookup, find and import all 3 type definitions for `Compute`, `JWT`, `UserRefreshClient`?

Comment: @user482594 Or you just find the type that the `getClient` method is part of, and reference it directly from there instead of re-creating the method signature.

Comment: Hm.. okay, I will try that. Thanks!